# When to put '-s' or -'es' after a noun in genetiv case?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

What I know is that, when there are more than two vowels , we put "-es" but in "Arzt" we put -"es", but what about "Zahnarzt" oder "Tierarzt"? We'll put "-es"? Or is there some other logic behind this ?

Comment: There is no simple rule, it depends on the word. In your example, however,  *Zahnarzt* and *Tierarzt* derive from *Arzt* and use the genitive form of their parent - *des Zahnarztes*. Feminine and plural words do not change from nominative to genitive ( like *der Ärztin* or *der Ärzte*). For others, both variants with *s* or *es* are possible (*s* likely is a shortening). And then there are irregular genitives..

Answer (score 2):

First recommendation: look into the dictionary, see [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28718/why-do-some-german-dictionaries-list-the-genitive-case-ending).
In many cases pronounciation already gives a hint: trying to pronounce "Arzts" without getting a knot in ones tongue gives an indication, why the *e* is useful here.

In composite substantives the composition has the same genitive ending.