# Why does the German dictionary show only 2nd and 3rd person conjugation?

Tags: verb, conjugation, dictionary

In the German dictionary I refer to often, there is the conjugation of verbs only for (du) and (er) as below (for word Können).
[image: in German dictionary : dedic.naver.com]

I know the conjugation for ich is kann. Is it because I can deduce the 1st person conjugation from kannst or kann? If so, what is the exact rule? just remove 'st' from 'kannst'?

In the example below, I cannot deduce 'Ich lese' from 'Du liest' or 'Er liest'.
[image]

Comment: I guess you'll have to ask the author of that dictionary.

Comment: @Em1 ok, I'll try..Thanks.

Comment: If you want to see all of forms of conjugation of a verb, you can have a look at this: http://konjugator.reverso.net/konjugation-deutsch.html

Comment: It's a compromise. Often only the 2nd and 3rd person conjugation are irregular or if other forms are irregular they can be deduced from the 2nd and 3rd person.

Comment: Loosely related: [Why do some German dictionaries list the genitive case ending?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/28718/9551)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- There are around 200 irregular verbs in German (unregelmäßige Verben or starke Verben) and they usually have changes within their roots only for personal pronouns *du* and *er/sie/es*. That's probably the reason why you normally find the conjugation for 2nd- and 3rd-person pronouns only.
- Now, whether an exact rule exists or not, there are actually 5 "categories" of irregular verbs:

The first 4 categories only have changes within 2nd- and 3rd-person pronouns (*du, er/sie/es*).

> 1. **i** instead of **e**
>
> > helfen: ich helfe - du ***hilfst*** - er/sie/es ***hilft***
> >
> > geben: ich gebe - du ***gibst*** - er/sie/es ***gibt***
> >
> > -others: sprechen, essen, sterben, werfen, a.o.
>
> 2. **ie** instead of **e**
>
> > sehen: ich sehe - du ***siehst*** - er/sie/es ***sieht***
> >
> > lesen: ich lese - du ***liest*** - er/sie/es ***liest***
> >
> > -others: stehlen, empfehlen, befehlen, a.o.
>
> 3. **ä** instead of **a**
>
> > fahren: ich fahre - du ***fährst*** - er/sie/es ***fährt***
> >
> > halten: ich halte - du ***hältst*** - er/sie/es ***hält***
> >
> > -others: fangen, schlafen, waschen, a.o.
>
> 4. **äu** instead of **au**
>
> > laufen: ich laufe - du ***läufst*** - er/sie/es ***läuft***
> >
> > saufen: ich saufe - du ***säufst*** - er/sie/es ***säuft***

The irregular verbs in 5th category have unpredictable changes in their roots and they can also be irregular for *ich, wir, ihr, sie/Sie*:

> 5. Special cases
>
> > haben: ich habe - du ***hast*** - er/sie/es ***hat***
> >
> > sein: ich ***bin*** - du ***bist*** - er/sie/es ***ist*** - wir ***sind*** - ihr ***seid*** - sie/Sie ***sind***
> >
> > wissen: ich ***weiß*** - du ***weißt*** - er/sie/es ***weiß***
> >
> > -others: werden, Modal Verbs (können, wollen, dürfen, sollen, mögen, müssen), a.o.

Comment: Nice answer! I just wonder how the plural versions wir/ihr/sie fit in.

Comment: @Marzipanherz, plural pronouns don't usually change their conjugations rules even on starke Verben. That means, you should always use **wir root+en**, **ihr root+t** and **sie/Sie root+en**. Just in some cases as shown in 5th categorie they might change, but those are few cases that you will easily learn and remember.

Comment: @J.Caicedo Thanks for the nice answer. That helps. And I gather the dictionary should better have shown the confjugation for 'Ich' when it's an irregular verbe. (because plural form is easy? :) )

Comment: @ChanKim, you'll find all forms in the one-and-only official dictionary: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/halten

Comment: @ChanKim Given the special behavior of *können*, I would've expected to have a separate entry for the 1st person singular following this answer. So, yes, they should've shown it, especially as the otherwise deduced *könne* is an existing word form with another meaning (Konjunktiv I)

Comment: *sollen* seems regular to me.